# Associated filter query in sequelizejs

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to do a associated filter query using sequelizejs.

The synario is as follows,

I have a `User` model which contains couple of attributes and a `Access` model which has one to one relation with `User` which is mapped as below

```
User.hasOne(Access);
```

Now i want to query all `User` models which have a particular access flag in `Access` model.

Will i be able to do this via Eager loading, i know its possible to filter via attributes in `User` model but how can i filter based on attributes in `Access` model.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution for this. You can do like this

```
User.findAll({
    include: [
       {model: Access, where: {myAttribute: 'Hansen'}}
    ]
})
```

Take a look here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/1199

Answer (score 2):

With `v3.12.0`, you can perform the following query associations:

```
User.findAll({
  where: {
    '$Access.myAttribute$': 'Hansen',
  },
  include: [{ model: Access }],
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3095#issuecomment-149277205